# Does SQL Server 2000 support user defined table type?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am passing datatable as input parameter to sp. For that reason I chose way of creating user defined table type. I am working on SQL Server 2012, but developing version is 2000. Does SQL Server 2000 support user defined table type?

Comment: No, it is available from 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only from SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not supported in SQL Server 2000. If you want to use that then you have to [switch to Sql Server 2008](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx) or may be the one which you are using SQL Server 2012. :)